# Read corpus from a csv file in Orange3

Tags: text-mining, orange

I have twitter text as an Excel file: every line is one one tweet. How do I view this corpus in Orange3? I don't understand why I can't simply see this corpus. As you can see in the image below, the channel is red and there's nothing in Corpus View, while Data Table shows some data
[image: can't view corpus]

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn it to Corpus using this widget in Text Mining tab:
[image: Corpus Widget]